# Measure data transfer rate (bandwidth) between 2 apps across network using C++, how to get unbiased and accurate result?

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, network-programming, bandwidth

I am trying to measure IO data transfer rate (bandwidth) between 2 simulation applications (written in C++). I created a very simple perfclient and perfserver program just to verify that my approach in calculating the network bandwidth is correct before implementing this calculation approach in the real applications. So in this case, I need to do it programatically (NOT using Iperf).

I tried to run my perfclient and perfserver program on various domain (localhost, computer connected to ethernet,and computer connected to wireless connection). However I always get about the similar bandwidth on each of these different hosts, around 1900 Mbps (tested using data size of 1472 bytes). Is this a reasonable result, or can I get a better and more accurate bandwidth?

Should I use 1472 (which is the ethernet MTU, not including header) as the maximum data size for each send() and recv(), and why/why not? I also tried using different data size, and here are the average bandwidth that I get (tested using ethernet connection), which did not make sense to me because the number exceeded 1Gbps and reached something like 28 Gbps.

```
SIZE    BANDWIDTH
1KB     1396 Mbps
2KB     2689 Mbps
4KB     5044 Mbps
8KB     9146 Mbps
16KB    16815 Mbps
32KB    22486 Mbps
64KB    28560 Mbps
```

**HERE is my current approach:**
I did a basic ping-pong fashion loop, where the client continuously send bytes of data stream to the server program. The server will read those data, and reflect (send) the data back to the client program. The client will then read those reflected data (2 way transmission). The above operation is repeated 1000 times, and I then divided the time by 1000 to get the average latency time. Next, I divided the average latency time by 2, to get the 1 way transmission time. Bandwidth can then be calculated as follow:

```
bandwidth = total bytes sent / average 1-way transmission time
```

Is there anything wrong with my approach? How can I make sure that my result is not biased? Once I get this right, I will need to test this approach in my original application (not this simple testing application), and I want to put this performance testing result in a scientific paper.

**EDIT:** 
***I have solved this problem. Check out the answer that I posted below.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure and solve this out :-)
As I mentioned in the question, regardless of the network architecture that I used (localhost, 1Gbps ethernet card, Wireless connection, etc), my achieved bandwidth scaled up for up to 28Gbps. I have tried to bind the server IP address to several different IP addresses, as follow:

```
127.0.0.1  
IP address given by my LAN connection  
IP address given by my wireless connection
```

So I thought that this should give me correct result, in fact it didn't.
This was mainly because I was running both of the client and server program on the same computers (different terminal window, even though the client and server are both bound to different IP addresses). My guess is that this is caused by the internal loopback. This is the main reason why the result is so biased and not accurate.

Anyway, so I then tried to run the client on one workstation, and the server on another workstation, and I tested them using the different network connection, and it worked as expected :-)
On 1Gbps connection, I got about 9800 Mbps (0.96 Gbps), and on 10Gbps connection, I got about 10100 Mbps (9.86 Gbps). So this work exactly as I expected. So my approach is correct. Perfect !!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a need to reinvent the wheel [iperf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) was made to handle just this problem.

> Iperf was developed by NLANR/DAST as a modern alternative for measuring maximum TCP and UDP bandwidth performance. Iperf allows the tuning of various parameters and UDP characteristics. Iperf reports bandwidth, delay jitter, datagram loss.

Comment: Yes, I can use Iperf to monitor my network bandwidth in a general setting. What I need is to measure data transfer rate between 2 specific simulation applications that I wrote (not these perfclient and perfserver apps). They are both communicating with each other and the communication involves data IO exchange. So I want to be able to measure IO data transfer bandwidth between these two simulation applications.